# Sort order items before inserting into DB

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

Does anyone know how to sort order items before they are saved into DB? I mean after placing the order. Should I use the event `sales_order_place_before`?

Comment: Yeah, that should work. But while sorting you will have to be careful with bundle and config items. `sales_order_item` table does have `parent_item_id`.

Answer (score 0):

Magento not recommend the use of event Observer to edit data. It's better to use an after plugin (or a before plugin) method to sort your items before they are saved into database.

Comment: can you elaborate which class/method I should inject in plugin?